# I am trying to extract tweets using tweepy but getting an error. I tried searching everywhere but could not find the solution

Tags: tweepy, data-extraction

This is the code:

```
tweet_num = 0

def Tweet_Extract(num, query):

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query,include_entities =True,lang="en").items(num):

        if tweet.place is not None:
            #print ('tweet number: {}'.format(tweet_num), tweet.text, 
            tweet.place.full_name)
            # write data to csv
            csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at,
                                tweet.user.location,
                                tweet.user.followers_count,
                                tweet.user.friends_count,
                                tweet.text,
                                tweet.place.bounding_box.coordinates,
                                tweet.place.full_name,
                                tweet.place.country,
                                tweet.place.country_code,
                                tweet.place.place_type])
            tweet_num += 1


Tweet_Extract(200, 'google')
```

The error I am getting is:

```
  Tweet_Extract(200, 'google')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-147-b06a0bcdf1b0>", line 1, in <module>
    Tweet_Extract(200, 'google')

  File "<ipython-input-146-1333d1ed6365>", line 2, in Tweet_Extract
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query,include_entities = True,lang="en").items(num):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 47, in __next__
    return self.next()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 195, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 115, in next
    model = ModelParser().parse(self.method(create=True), data)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\parsers.py", line 100, in parse
    result = model.parse(method.api, json)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\models.py", line 308, in parse
    results.append(status_model.parse(api, status))

TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw'
```

Comment: You should post the entire error traceback. And it's a bad idea to write a general except block that passes everything. That doesn't help in error finding.

Comment: @TinNguyen I updated the error as suggested. What should I do with the except block?

Comment: You have not provided the entire error traceback. It's just a small section from it. Remove `try`, `except ..` and `pass` unindent once the try block. Run code again with the error.

Comment: @TinNguyen I made the changes and also provided the entire error traceback.

Comment: Are you authenticated to the API?

Comment: @TinNguyen yes, I am.